# Using the NewLateBinding class in C#?

Tags: dynamic, c#-2.0, com-interop

Unfortunately it seems I need to do some small amount of dynamic interop in C# 2.0. I discovered the [`NewLateBinding` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.newlatebinding.aspx) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161675/using-reflection-with-com-interop).  I was looking at the specification on MSDN and noted that it said

> Executes a late-bound property get or field access call. **This helper method is not meant to be called directly from your code.**
>   <sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

What is the risk of using this class's methods?  Is there any way around it without using C#4.0 or VB?

Comment: I'm betting that it's their way of telling you, "We had to expose this publicly, but we reserve the right to change it anytime we want in future versions".

Comment: I can't think of any reason to litter my code with comments MSDN says "don't use this" unless you are a language ninja, and if you can name off the top of your head the reflection classes etc... If they say don't use it, don't use it. You'll be better off.

Comment: @jball The interop in question was originally written to be used from VB6.  Dynamic interop was part of the picture then ...

Comment: @C. Ross I get why you might need it, I'm just saying that some internal MS technical writer was trying to warn outsiders away from those methods probably because MS doesn't want to guarantee how they work.

Comment: @jball I misunderstood, I thought you were referring to the com interop, I understand what you're saying.