# how to get/set value from Com interop object using dynamic by property name string

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, interop

I have following code:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("interopTypeName");
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
string propertyName = "somePropertyName";
// how to get somePropertyName from obj?
```

It is possible to do it without dynamic. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161675/using-reflection-with-com-interop) is [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s solution how to do it.
However it is interesting if it is possible to do it using dynamic.

Comment: System.Dynamic is not a substitute for Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Gravell has an opensource project called [FastMember](http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) that makes it easy to access properties using the code the [api dynamic generates](http://code.google.com/p/fast-member/source/browse/FastMember/CallSiteCache.cs).

```
var wrapped = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj); 
var result = wrapped[somePropertyName];
```